# when I'm making a request the session keeps expiring and asks me to go back to homepage

Tags: session, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data on potential recipients of unclaimed funds from a state comptrollers site but every time I send a request the program provides the skeleton of the page with a message stating that the session has expired and directs me to the homepage.

```
import csv
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as rq
from time import sleep 

'''state site scraper '''

url = 'https://ouf.osc.state.ny.us/ouf/YBKNMrFPZGWzwFD0f-Bd4w/YBK91'
re_quest = rq.get(url, allow_redirects=False,verify=False)
parse = bs(re_quest.text,'html.parser')

print (parse)
```

Comment: I really need help

Comment: When visiting the given link in your browser do you see anything unusual?

Comment: Not at all. I search for a name in input fields , get a list of names with reported information . Once I run the script I get the session expiration message